# Parse and remove a series of html files

Tags: html

I'd like to remove a series of elements like:

```
div-id="st-head" class="noprint"
```

from a html file.

Comment: Show example input with corresponding output please

Comment: Yes please cite a couple of the situations where this code is contained in these files. Otherwise this isn't much to go on.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is to delete that exact string and don't care where it's found or anything about context at all, just do this:

```
sed -i.bak 's/div-id="st-head" class="noprint"//g' a.html b.html c.html
```

That will remove every occurrence of that string from each html file listed and a copy of the original called `[filename.html].bak`.